Unity InputSystem sometimes not track touch ended events when clicking fast
i'am new with InputSystem from Unity and get problems with touch release events, so brifly i get that InputSystem sometimes not get tap end event when taps faster then FPS i suppose. I've add screen of my settings InputSystem Settings
Update mode set as Dynamic Update, i can change it on something else but problem stays, situation with miss release tap events posible. Also i've add screens of Input Debug window where you can see problem that InputSystem create new touches when old's ones stays processes as active.Start state born of problem increased problem.
In way when solving problem with touch release events is impossible by settings of Input System should i somehow manually remove old touches which infinity freezing in began state to free up memory?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try to decrease the tap time .. see Default Tap Time Default duration for Tap and MultiTap Interactions. Also used by by touchscreen Devices to distinguish taps from to new touches. if you tap faster than this then it treats it as a new tap instead of the same .. the ended event might be somehow related to it (the text is like this in the API btw .. someone should fix that ^^)

@derHugo extra small  values for that parameters still produce this problem, may be it's more louve level problem or depend from simulator mode

Any way i use mouse for device simulator which click interprets as touches, and if fast click looks as new touches by logic previous ones must be release and not stay in move state.
